# How do I have multiple docker images available in one stage Git lab CI

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - art

image: golang:1.9.2

variables:   
  BIN_NAME: example
  ARTIFACTS_DIR: artifacts   
  GO_PROJECT: example
  GOPATH: /go

before_script:
  - mkdir -p ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}
  - mkdir -p ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/${ARTIFACTS_DIR}
  - go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
  - cp -r ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/* ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}/
  - cd ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}

test:   
  stage: test
  script:
    # Run all tests
    go test -run ''

build:   
 stage: build
 script:
    # Compile and name the binary as `hello`
    - go build -o hello
    - pwd
    - ls -l hello
    # Execute the binary
    - ./hello
    # Move to gitlab build directory
    - mv ./hello ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}   artifacts:
    paths:
    - ./hello
```

The issue is my program is dependant on both Go and Mysql...

I am aware i can have a different docker image for each stage but my test stage needs both

```
go test & MySql
```

What I have looked into:

I have learn ho to create my own docker image based using docker commit and also how to use a docker file to build and image up.

However I have hear there are way to link docker containers together using docker compose, and this seems like a better method...

I have no idea how to go about this in GitLab, I know I need a `compose.yml` file but not sure where to put it, whats need to go in it, does it create an image that I then link to from my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file?

Perhaps this is over kill and there is a simpler way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand your tests need a MySQL server in order to work and that you are using some kind of MySQL client or driver in your Go tests.

You can use a Gitlab CI [`service`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-a-service) which will be made available during your `test` job. GitlabCI will run a MySQL container beside your Go container which will be reachable via it's name from the Go container. For example:

```
test:   
  stage: test
  services: 
  - mysql:5.7
  variables:
    # Configure mysql environment variables (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
    MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  script:
    # Run all tests
    go test -run ''
```

Will start a MySQL container and it will be reachable from the Go container via hostname `mysql`. Note you'll need to define `variables` for MySQL startup as per the [Environment variables section of image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) (such as Root password or database to create)

You can also define the service globally (will be made available for each job in your build) and use an [alias](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#available-settings-for-services) so the MySQL server will be reachable from another hostname.

Comment: just testing and i get the following on ci/lint  Error: (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 33 column 1

Comment: It looks like a typo in your gitla-ci yaml file, are you sure it's correctlt YAML formatted? You can try de CI Lint (there's a big button on the CI page of your Gitlab instance)

Comment: My bad, it's `services` not `service` :) just edited